# How to determine a qualitative graph of a function in the neighbourhood of a point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have the function $f(x)=(x^2(e^x-1))^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and I would like to  determine a qualitative graph of the function in the neighbourhood of $x=0$. I know that there might be an inflection point in $x=0$, so personally, I would most likely calculate the second derivative of the function $f(x)$ in the point $x=0$, but I don't know how to actually determine if there's an inflection point and what kind of inflection it is.

Comment: This is not a graph theory question ^^ graph theory is the study of graphs, as in nodes and edges...

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$; the left and right limits of $f'(x)$ as $x\to 0$ approach $\infty$.